# Passing callback function created in my custom controller

Tags: php, magento, callback

I have the follow code snippet and works well:

```
<?php
require_once(FOLDER_ROOT . "/lib/transaction/RetornoBanco.php");
require_once(FOLDER_ROOT . "/lib/transaction/RetornoFactory.php");

$fileName = 'test.txt';

function rowProcess($self, $numLn, $vrow) {
    print ($numLn . ' - ' . $vrow);
}

$test = RetornoFactory::getRetorno($fileName, 'rowProcess');
$retorno = new RetornoBanco($test);
$retorno->process();
```

The getRetorno function uses 'rowProcess' as a handler function.
But now I'm trying do it in my custom controller (on my own Magento Extension, looks like Zend Controllers).

For each line of my file (test.txt), rowProcess runs.

But now, in my controller, rowProcess has a class. 
My controller:

```
class MY_CLASS_HERE extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function uploadAction()
    {   
        //just to simplify, this uploaded file exists
        $fileName = '/home/user/public_html/app/files/file.RET';

        $test = RetornoFactory::getRetorno($fileName, "rowProcess");
        $retorno = new RetornoBanco($test);
        $retorno->process();

        echo 'My Controller Here';
    }

    public function rowProcess($self, $numLn, $vrow)
    {
        print ($numLn . ' - ' . $vrow);
        //I'm creating log to prevent it is not a problem for standard output
        Mage::log($numLn . ' - ' . $vrow);
        //This function log is default in Magento and works without problems.
    }
}
```

My controller works well but now the handler doesn't print nothing!
I think it's wrong because now my function handler inside a class and getRetorno function can not use it. What could I do to fix this?

Comment: check this: [link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php)  
  In your case maybe you should use $test = RetornoFactory::getRetorno($fileName, array(${the instance of MY_CLASS_HERE}, "rowProcess"));

Comment: try this
$test = RetornoFactory::getRetorno($fileName, array($this,"rowProcess"));

Answer (score 0):

How about using like this? Can you try it?

```
    $test = RetornoFactory::getRetorno($fileName, $this->rowProcess);
```